# Problem to use setBinding to import a library on settings.gradle of Android project

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying set up a groovy library of Flutter to a AndroidStudio project. To do it, I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

On second step of tutorial (Android), I must configure `settings.gradle` file to bind lib, but when I type the code of tutorial the `Binding` object ins't found.

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))                                 // new
evaluate(new File(                                                      // new
  settingsDir.parentFile,                                               // new
  'my_flutter/.android/include_flutter.groovy'                          // new
))
```

I've options to import, but none works.

**Options to import**

[image]

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @RahulDevanavar -> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28605

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below code if you are use the gradle 7.1 and above. Do not import Binding package, let it be **RED** and sync the project.

```
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "AddToAndroid"
include ':app'
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))                                 // new
evaluate(new File(                                                      // new
        settingsDir.parentFile,                                               // new
        'demoflutter/.android/include_flutter.groovy'                          // new
))
```

And Add below lines to your Android's Project build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Sync fails because it can't find `Binding` symbol.

Answer (score -2):

you may create my_flutter folder in '~/Path/MyApp'
you should put it in '~/Path/'